# How to configure Oracle Java7 to generate a thread dump upon heap dump?

Tags: java, java-7, heap-dump, thread-dump

I am hunting a problem in my java app which use a great high heap memory. I have managed to make Oracle Java to dump heap before Full GC(HeapDumpBeforeFullGC), but the thread dump is also needed. I have googled for a solution, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no such solution for oracle jdk, I will use IBM Jdk which will dump both thread and heap if turn on the switch:  -Xdump:heap:events=fullgc

Answer (score 0):

download IBM support assistance from the official site free for personal use. It's a very good tool to analyze java heap.

Comment: Also work very well for oracle java . Thread dump analysis tool is also very good.

Comment: Are you using any managed server or just standalone JVM?
Also elaborate the scenario. What is the actual issue e.g outofmemory or thread hung?

Comment: I need the ThreadDumpBeforeFullGC option which does not exist.

Comment: you need to configure the same which triggers ThreadDump on that incident.

e.g. if you want a heapdump on out-of-memory, you can start Java with the option -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Comment: If your code is running on any managed server such as websphere or jboss or weblogic, then there are certain setting that need to be enabled.